# Simplex Algorithm - why so complicated?

Tags: algorithm, numeric, mathematical-optimization

Recently I was introduced to the simplex algorithm for optimizing linear problems. I think I understand how it works, but I don't know, why it is that complicated.

1. Why do we have to use the pivot- row/column/element. If I see this correctly it is just a Gauss elimination which eliminates Elements in a specific order. Why does the order matter? Is it due to numerical noise? If everything is calculated precisely the ordering shouldn't be important, right?
2. In all examples I encountered so far (not too many to be fair) all slack variables are set to zero in the end. Why did we introduce them in the first place and didn't just rewrite all inequations  directly as equations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because an explanation of the simplex method is requested. Stackoverflow is a site for programmers. You might get a better answer at some other forum / site or in some introductory book on linear programming. My personal favorite is [Chvatal: Linear Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Programming-Series-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0716715872) but there are many, *many* other good books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pivoting is NOT Gaussian elimination. The tableau is likely to have about as many zeros after the pivot as before it. The order of pivoting is chosen to maintain the simplex constraint (always moving from one vertex of the feasible space to another), and to do so efficiently (by making maximum progress along the objective with each move).
2. Slack variables are zero for constraints which bind the solution. It sounds like the problems you looked at didn't have any non-binding constraints.